# Is there a way to position background image center to exact coordinates?

Tags: html, css, coordinates, background-image, background-position

I have a background image in body, svg ordinary circle.

At background-position: 0%, 0% this circle appears on the top left corner of the page.
But I want this circle's ***center*** to be exactly at 0,0 (top left corner) and stay there, no matter the device width.

I can manually center it with negative percentages or pixels or em/rem but it doesn't stay there when I change browser width.

Can anyone help?

Here's the link from codepen.io:
https://codepen.io/sandro-bochorishvili/pen/KKMjezN

Actual Code:
css

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color:  hsl(185, 75%, 39%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Rfg.svg),
                    url(https://svgshare.com/i/RgK.svg);
  background-position: -20rem -34rem, 72em 15em;

  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  padding: 0 2em 0 2em;
}
```

Comment: If you specify the offset in pixels it should not move. Can you add a snippet?

Comment: That's right, assuming `background-size` is set to `cover`, the image can stretch in X or Y axis (or both) depending on available space. However, there are tons of ways to do this so we would need a real life example to suggest the most viable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually I figured it out, but I need the same thing on bottom right corner but that's a tricky one, pixels don't work, the circle is moving to the right and disappears from the screen (when decreasing width)

Comment: Here's the link from codepen.io: https://codepen.io/sandro-bochorishvili/pen/KKMjezN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine relative and absolute dimensions you can use `calc`, in your case it'll be  `background-position: -20rem -34rem, calc(100% + 20rem) calc(100% + 34rem);`

```css
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color:  hsl(185, 75%, 39%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Rfg.svg),
    url(https://svgshare.com/i/RgK.svg);
 background-position: -20rem -34rem, calc(100% + 20rem) calc(100% + 34rem);

  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  padding: 0 2em 0 2em;
}
```